# YII framework form ajax validation only part of input

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii

I have form build with yii framework.
The first 2 inputs is "first_name" and "last_name" and I have many more inputs in the same form.
I'm checking validation with "ajaxSubmitButton" and I want to check first only "first_name" and "last_name" pass the validation and If they do next time when user will submit its would check all form.

Model -> rules

```
        array('first_name, last_name', 'length', 'min'=>2 , 'on' => 'setup'),
                    array('first_name, last_name , email, subject , message', 'length', 'min'=>2 , 'on' => 'submit'),
```

Ajax Button on View ->

```
         <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton( 'Submit',
                                                                    CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('SubmitForm')),
                              array(
                    'error'=>'js:function(){
                                      alert(\'error\');
                                            }',
                            'beforeSend'=>'js:function(){
                                           alert(\'beforeSend\');
                                                                    }',
                                                                    'success'=>'js:function(data){
                                                                        alert(data);


                                                                    }',
                                                                    'complete'=>'js:function(){
                                                                       // alert(\'complete\');
                                                                    }',
                                                                    'update'=>'#updatebox',
                                                                    ) ,array('id'=>'submit')
                                                                );
                                ?>
```

Controller >

```
    public function actionMessageForm()
{
    $model = new Message;
        if(isset($_POST['Message']))
        {
              $model->attributes=$_POST['Message'];
              $valid = $model->validate('setup');
              if($valid)
              {
                  echo "pass";
                $model->save();
              } 
              else
              {
                   echo "failed";
              }

        }

}
```

How can I check partly inputs?
What I'm doing Wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure i understood you. You need to validate your form twice - first time you validate only "first_name" and "last_name" inputs and after that you do what?

Comment: After I'll validate all form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your controller.  This:

```
public function actionMessageForm()
{
    $model = new Message;
        if(isset($_POST['Message']))
        {
              $model->attributes=$_POST['Message'];
              $valid = $model->validate('setup');
```

should be this:

```
public function actionMessageForm()
{
    $model = new Message;
        if(isset($_POST['Message']))
        {
              $model->scenario = 'setup'; <-- changed
              $model->attributes=$_POST['Message'];
              $valid = $model->validate(); <-- passing a value in here is passing an attribute
```

or this:

```
public function actionMessageForm()
{
        if(isset($_POST['Message']))
        {
             $model = new Message('setup');
```

Does that help?

Comment: Its working but in the client side validation everything looks like this passed the validation. despite it isn't

Comment: Client side validation probably won't work well for this setup, as you are changing your scenarios midway through. The client side JavaScript won't be rewritten at the same time. It might be worth using Ajax validation instead. And if things are now working, I'd appreciate you marking my answer as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: How can I change the validation so it would trow error if the user not field input correctly real time with the scenarios?

Comment: Good question :-) I'm not sure, as I haven't done much with Ajax validation. I'd think you would need to check in your controller to see if your username/password validation scenario passes and if it does, then change the scenario on the model (like in my first example) and then try re validating. But it might be worth another question to get more input on

Answer (score 2):

use scenarios bro

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/

make one scenario 'buttafuoco' (call it what you will) where only the first and last name are required

if that validates, switch the scenario to 'blagojevich' (a new scenario) where all fields are required.

you might have to store the current scenario name in session or a post variable